# Do I need recursive function - Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the below table and need to calculate Rooms Available. Basically I need to take the calculated field from above row and use it to calculate the current row. I tried preceding function but I can't reuse the calculated field.

Can we do it without recursive function? If not even recursive will work.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TransactionDt | Total#ofrooms | RoomsSold | TotalRoomsAvailable | calculatelike |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1/1/16     |      15       |     1     |         14          |    (15-1)     |
|    1/2/16     |      15       |     2     |         12          |    (14-2)     |
|    1/3/16     |      15       |     1     |         ?           |    (12-1)     |
|    1/4/16     |      15       |     0     |         ?           |    (11-0)     |
|    1/5/16     |      15       |     0     |         ?           |    (11-0)     |
|    1/6/16     |      15       |     1     |         ?           |    (11-1)     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I know a cumulative sum (of rooms sold) will work but I do not want to use that since my problem is complicated and I have given an simplified example.

Comment: Then, tell us your actual problem.

Comment: Hi @Noel - If the above solution is resolved, then I can figure it out easily. It's hard to reproduce and explain. thx

Comment: But, you are saying you dont want to use cumulative sum for some unspecified reason.

Answer (score 0):

A cumulative sum is the obvious solution:

```
select t.*,
       (TotalNumOfRooms - 
        sum(RoomsSold) over (order by TransactionDt range between unbounded preceding and current row)
       ) as TotalRoomsAvailable
from t;
```

If this doesn't meet your needs, then you should ask *another* question.  The question you have asked here clearly has a simple solution (using cumulative sum).  If it doesn't help you, then it is not the right question.